# How do I set the highlight level to syntax in phpstorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

Is there any way to set the highlight to syntax for all my project?

I want all of my projects have highlighting level like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJCsj.jpg]

Comment: Well .. you can disable all inspections (click on "Configure inspections" and disable all of them/selected only) -- that's basically what it does but for current file only. https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/changing-highlighting-level-for-the-current-file.html

Comment: yeah i know it , but i want to apply my inspections to all projects not just current file only :(

Comment: *"but i want to apply my inspections to all projects not just current file only"* That's why you need to click on "Configure inspections" and do it THERE (it will affect ALL files in a project) because your screenshot affects current file only.

Comment: aw yeah , thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

1. That functionality from your screen shot -- it affects *current file only*. As far as I'm aware there is no such settings that will do this for ALL files in one simple click (i.e. similar screen).
2. What you can do here .. is to create and *use separate Inspections Profile* where all unwanted inspections (in your case all for HTML & PHP languages) are disabled. For that just click on `Configure Inspections` link and do it all there

   The same settings page can also be reached via `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections`.